# Are Batman and Superman brothers?

Tags: dc, batman, superman, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

### Are they half brothers?

On the [DC Comics site](http://www.dccomics.com/blog/2013/04/02/superman-and-batman-best-friendsand-brothers) it states that Martha Wayne went into the witness protection program after she was targeted by a mob hit,

> Millionaire Bruce Wayne is just a kid when he watched his parents get
>   gunned down during a mugging in Gotham City. The crime would define
>   his life, as he dedicated himself to becoming the world’s greatest
>   weapon against crime—the Batman. What the world doesn’t know is that
>   Bruce’s mother, **Martha Wayne, was the real target for the mob hit** the
>   night that Bruce’s parents were murdered. While in the ambulance it
>   was discovered that she was **still alive**, and the doctors were able to
>   save her. She signed over guardianship of Bruce to the family butler,
>   Alfred Pennyworth, in hopes that the young boy would be protected, and
>   she was put into the **Witness Protection Program** and sent to
>   Smallville, Kansas—a quiet town where nothing ever happens.
>
> **There Martha met and married a nice young man named Jonathan Kent.**
>   With a new inability to carry a child due to the bullet wound, Martha
>   and Jonathan were unable to have the baby they so longed for. However,
>   their prayers were answered when out of the sky, a rocket landed in a
>   nearby field as the couple was driving by. **There was a small baby in**
>   t**he rocket who they adopted and gave the name Clark Kent**, and who
>   would **grow up to be Superman!**

So by that it would seem that 'Martha Wayne' and 'Martha Kent' are the seem to be the same person, which would make Bruce Wayne and Clark Kent half brothers.

And in the movie *Batman vs Superman*, we see Batman stop trying to kill Superman after he hears Superman mention "Martha".

I don't know if this holds any significance?

Is this true?

Answer (score 20):

Actually same site you linked says that those were fake bios:

> [...] other April Fool’s Day prank?
>
> In addition to the fake projects, we posted a link to “newly updated”
>   profile pages for Batman and Superman, and if you read any of them,
>   you may have noticed a shocking connection between Bruce Wayne and
>   Clark Kent…and their mothers.
>
> [...]
>
> Yes, they’re not just best friends and two of the most beloved super
>   heroes on the planet. Superman and Batman are also half-brothers.
>
> Or at least they were for one day in the hearts and minds of some of
>   our fans. The authentic profiles have now been restored to the Batman
>   and Superman pages, but not before several of you commented on the
>   changes. And why not? Stranger things have happened in comics. And it
>   is a pretty big coincidence that both their mothers are named Martha.
>
> So what do you think? Were you fooled by the fake bios?

I. e. affirming that this was an elaborate April Fool's Day joke.

Comment: And even if weren't a joke, it still wouldn't make them only step-brothers, not half-brothers, let alone brothers.

Comment: @JörgWMittag very true

Comment: @JörgWMittag, no imagination what so ever.

Comment: Half-siblings share a *biological* parent. Step-siblings are by marriage only.

Comment: When I was just a little boy, I read a black-and-white reprint of an old comic book story (Silver Age, "World's Finest Comics #146"), in which Batman briefly thought he might secretly be a long-lost sibling of Superman's -- born with the name "Bruce-El," and rocketed to the Earth from Krypton at the same time Kal-El was, but perhaps had been exposed to Gold Kryptonite and had lost his superpowers when he was a mere toddler, and then somehow was adopted by the Waynes and raised as their son. (It all turned out to be a false alarm -- he really was the natural son of Thomas and Martha Wayne.)

Comment: @Lorendiac *Bruce-El*??? Batman really knows how to screw with Supes

Comment: Not a coincidence -- all women in the 1940s were named "Martha."

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, in the mid 2000s *Superman/Batman* comic, there **was** an alternative reality where *they were raised as adopted brothers.*

This was issue #17, basically a "forced changed timeline" situation, where 3 criminals from the 3000th century: Lightning Lord, Cosmic King, and Saturn Queen (essentially evil siblings of the *Legion of Superheroes* trinity Lightning Lad, Cosmic Boy and Saturn Girl) came back to "our time," eliminated a number of the other heroes [Aquaman, Green Lantern, Flash and Martian Manhunter] then "arranged" to pick up Bruce and Clark at their pivotal origin moments. They then raised them as their "children" and let them develop their superhero personas, but guided the boys with *their* intentions, turning them into dictators of their world with their respective intelligence, skills, and abilities.

Here's a scan:

[image: Batman and Superman visit their parents]

On the next page, Superman basically alludes to them being family:

[image: meet the parents]

The only other story I could think of that comes close to this would be *Superman: Speeding Bullets* where Kal-el's ship landed in Gotham, was found by the Waynes and *he* was raised as "Bruce," but since Bruce *himself* wasn't there, it doesn't really count to my mind.