# How has the Batman V Superman climactic reveal been treated elsewhere?

Tags: dc, batman, superman, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Batman V Superman dealt with a piece of information in a very mocking way:

> Martha Kent and Martha Wayne have the same first name.

Has this piece of information been better handled in other media?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138924/are-batman-and-superman-brothers

Comment: You may mean [climactic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/climactic) rather than [climatic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/climatic) (although I’m not entirely convinced either applies, to be honest).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yes on climactic, thanks for the edit. Didn't know how else to describe the poorly handled act transition with out spoiling it.

Answer (score 7):

The new X-Men Annual #1 references this iconic scene. Suffice to say, it's with a certain level of disrespect.

[image]

Comment: I love this level of disrespect.

Comment: Is... is the guy on the left Shog? :P